# all method of gem module: devise shows undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I installed gem module: device for user authentification. 
It is working well for login/logout. 
But when I add any method of devise in Controller and View, all response is "undefined method"

- e.g1 undefined method `user_signed_in?' for
  #<#:0x0000001dddecb8>
- e.g2 undefined method `authenticate_user!' for#

Anyone encounter the same problems? Could you let me know any solutions for it?

I'm using 
 Rails 3.1.1
 ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
 devise (2.1.2)

Thanks 
--Katsuya

Comment: Can you please provide examples of the code you are using that is showing these errors?